# SharePoint Calculated list IF statement based on two columns results

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I have columns called Refresh Due and Refresh Priority and I want the results in these columns to provide a result in a third column called Priority Order.

Refresh Due is a calculated column that references warranty dates and provides the result- "Due" or "Still Under Warranty".

Refresh Priority is a Yes or No choice column (this column is if I want to prioritize a refresh of an item before its due).

I want Priority order to display 1, 2 or 3, number 1 being top priority

- Refresh Due = "Due" Refresh Priority = "No"    - Result "2"
- Refresh Due = "Due" Refresh Priority = "Yes"    - Result "1"
- Refresh Due = "Still Under Warranty" Refresh Priority = "Yes"    - Result "1"
- Refresh Due = "Still Under Warranty" Refresh Priority = "No"    - Result "3"

I have gone through google searches and suggested links on here but not found a result that works, I have tried the following which gives me one or two results but not all of them.

This one I found online but fails syntax:

```
=IF([Refresh Due]="Due","2",IF(AND([Refresh Due]="Still Under Warranty",[Priority Refresh]="Yes","1"),IF(AND([Refresh Due]="Due",[Priority Refresh]="Yes","1","3"))))
```

This one only partially works, will change from 2 to 1 but dependent only on the Refresh Due column, the Refresh Priority has no effect:

```
=IF([Refresh Due]="Due","2",IF(AND([Refresh Due]="Still Under Warranty",[Priority Refresh]="Yes","1"),IF([Refresh Due]="Due",[Priority Refresh]="Yes","1")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF([Refresh Due]="Due",IF([Priority Refresh]="Yes","1","2"),IF([Refresh Due]="Still Under Warranty",IF([Priority Refresh]="Yes","1","2"),""))
```

**OR**:

```
=IF([Priority Refresh]="Yes","1",IF([Refresh Due]="Due","2","3"))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Thank you, i knew i was over complicating it, the second formula you suggested worked the first formula didn't work, again thank you for your help.